# Pins are not switching

Tags: arduino

I am trying to make pins 13, 12, 10 and 9 to switch between high and low. That is, when pin 13 is high, pin 12 should be low, then pin 10 should be high and pin 9 should be low.

Code:

```cpp
unsigned char driver[4] ={13, 12, 10, 9};
String mystring = "";
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
      pinMode(driver[i], OUTPUT);
  }
}

void backward(){
  digitalWrite(driver[0], HIGH);
  digitalWrite(driver[1], LOW);
  digitalWrite(driver[2], HIGH);
  digitalWrite(driver[3], LOW);
}
void forward(){
  digitalWrite(driver[0], LOW);
  digitalWrite(driver[1], HIGH);
  digitalWrite(driver[2], LOW);
  digitalWrite(driver[3], HIGH);  
}
void STOP(){
  digitalWrite(driver[0], LOW);
  digitalWrite(driver[1], LOW);
  digitalWrite(driver[2], LOW);
  digitalWrite(driver[3], LOW);   
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  while(Serial.available()){
    delay(10);
    char mychar = Serial.read();
    if(mychar == '\0')
      break;
    mystring += mychar;
  }

  if(mystring == "F" || mystring == "f"){
    forward();
    mystring = "";
    Serial.println("moving forward!");
  }
  else if(mystring == "B" || mystring == "b"){
    backward();
    mystring = "";
    Serial.println("moving backward!");
  }
  else if(mystring == "S" || mystring == "s"){
    STOP();
    mystring = "";
    Serial.println("stopped!");
  }
  else
    mystring = "";
}
```

When I test it, there is no switching, that is when moving backward, pin 13 is high throughout, pin 12 is low throughout, pin 10 is high throughout, and pin 9 is low throughout.

Comment: please do you have a solution?

Comment: When you run the code, does the "moving forward!" or "moving backward!" gets printet when you type F or B?

Comment: yes they get printed

Comment: Does the LED attached to pin 13 "L" light up when you press "B"?

Comment: it does but i want it to go off then light up again

Comment: Dosent it turn off if you press "S"? I'v just testet the code on a boat and it works as expected. Perhaps you could tell in more details what you want it to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146912/discussion-between-johnnydevv-and-xerxex).

Comment: Also posted at https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/39604

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
unsigned char driver[4] ={13, 12, 10, 9};
String mystring = "";
String state = "S";
long lastSwitch;
long switchIntaval = 10;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
      pinMode(driver[i], OUTPUT);
  }
}

void backward(){
  digitalWrite(driver[0], HIGH);
  digitalWrite(driver[1], LOW);
  digitalWrite(driver[2], HIGH);
  digitalWrite(driver[3], LOW);
}
void forward(){
  digitalWrite(driver[0], LOW);
  digitalWrite(driver[1], HIGH);
  digitalWrite(driver[2], LOW);
  digitalWrite(driver[3], HIGH); 
}
void STOP(){
  digitalWrite(driver[0], LOW);
  digitalWrite(driver[1], LOW);
  digitalWrite(driver[2], LOW);
  digitalWrite(driver[3], LOW); 
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  while(Serial.available()){
    char mychar = Serial.read();
    if(mychar == '\0')
      break;
    mystring += mychar;
    delay(1);
  }
  if(state != "S" && state != "s") {
    if(millis()-lastSwitch >= switchIntaval) {
      lastSwitch = millis();
      for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        digitalWrite(driver[i], !digitalRead(driver[i]));
        //Serial.println("Switching: " + String(i));
      }
    }
  }
  if(mystring == "F" || mystring == "f"){
    state = mystring;
    forward();
    mystring = "";
    Serial.println("moving forward!");
  }
  else if(mystring == "B" || mystring == "b"){
    state = mystring;
    backward();
    mystring = "";
    Serial.println("moving backward!");
  }
  else if(mystring == "S" || mystring == "s"){
    state = mystring;
    STOP();
    mystring = "";
    Serial.println("stopped!");
  }
  else
    mystring = "";
}
```